# How to show Modal to user before changing routes in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I'm wondering if I'm just not using the right vocabulary in my search - but what I thought might be cool for an app I'm working on would be:

1. A user starts editing their post.
2. In case they go back or press a tab to go to another page before
   they press "Update".
3. The screen change is intercepted and a modal shows up and asks if
   they want to keep their changes.

I know you can add event handlers - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/ but I'm not sure if these are what I need, I've tested and the prevent default didn't seem to do what I thought it would. That and I couldn't find a way to find what the next intended route that the app would need to go to once they have said "Dismiss" on the modal.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You can use back handler to achieve this functionality. when user press back button show him the alert, if user press ok then goBack or if user press cancel then remain on same screen.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own modal and back button so you can control what each item do

```
this.state={
  modalConfirm: false
    }

goBack = () => { //your goback function }
cancel = () => { this.setState ({modalConfirm :false})


<View>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setState({modalConfirm: true})>
   <Icon name='arrow-left' />
 </TouchableOpacity>

 <Modal visible={this.state.modalConfirm}>
   <Text>Do you want to go back? </Text>
   <Button title='Go back' onPress={this.goBack} />
   <Button title='No' onPress={this.cancel} />
 </Modal>

 <View>
  //your content
 </View>
</View>
```